# Pipeline PowerShell XML objects after namespace declaration

Tags: xml, powershell, pipeline

I have this PowerShell piece of code, which works.

```bsh
$xml = [xml](gc '.\test.xml')
$ns = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $xml.NameTable
$ns.AddNamespace("ns", "randomnamespace")

$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("//ns:tag", $ns)

# print all nodes
foreach ($node in $nodes) {
    Write-Host $node.anotherTag " - " $node.anotherTag.Substring(0,7)
}
```

I want to put it in one line to use it as PowerShell command because I can't change the execution policy.

I tried the following:

```bsh
$xml = [xml](gc '.\test.xml') | $ns = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $_.NameTable | $ns.AddNamespace('ns', 'tag') | $xml.selectNodes('//ns:anotherTag', $ns) | foreach {Write-Host $_.anotherTag' - ' $_.anotherTag(0,7)}"
```

but I get the error message

> Expressions only allowed as first element in Pipeline ...NameTable | $ns.AddNamespace('ns',..)

and I can't declare the namespace before reading the XML file.

Is there any way to get this working?

Comment: You can still paste the content into a window even if you can't change the execution policy. Would not recommend doing this as a one-liner, too much code. But if I can't dissuade you, use semi-colon `;` to separate commands and you can shortcut `foreach` with `$xml.selectNodes("//ns:tag", $ns)
 | % { $_.anotherTag ...}`

Comment: `|` is for connecting the STDOUT of one command to the STDIN of another command. If you just want to run one command after the other separate them with semicolons.

Comment: thanks, it can be so simple sometimes :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use pipe `|`, use semicolon `;` instead